# Why 60+ console-kit-daemon processes?

Tags: process, console-kit

I have over 60 processes of `console-kit-daemon` that won't stop reappearing after I've used `sudo killall console-kit-daemon`. I have no idea what the daemon is for.

I'm running ubuntu 10.04. What's going on?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

They're not processes, they're threads under one process.

By default htop shows threads and in this case, is very misleading. You can alter this by going into `Setup` (<kbd>F2</kbd>), `Display options` and checking `Hide userland threads`.

[image]

Press <kbd>F10</kbd> when you're done.

Comment: Here is some more info on what ConsoleKit actually does: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/ConsoleKit/doc/ConsoleKit.html

Comment: <kbd>F10</kbd> - good joke. It opens terminal file menu.